# How to disable a URL after specific time considering the code is deployed in one time zone and client can used the app anywhere

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, time, client-server

I have an application in which, a URL is to be clicked for financial transactions, so for security reasons, I want to disable this link after a specific time, but the problem is link has not expired even after a specific time period as the code is deployed in one time zone and client is using the app on another time zone. The URL is expiring randomly.

I want to synchronize with the time period specified for the URL to expire so that the URL will be disabled after a specific time when the client uses the app anywhere across time zones.

I have tried various approaches:

**Approach 1: Using time
#PYTHON**

import time

expiration_time = int(time.time()) + 20

url_temp = f"https://example.com?expiration_time={expiration_time}"

**Approach 2: Using HTML**

If we modify the HTML page, then it can't work in the app. Also, we don't want to use this approach, as this will not work in the connecting application

**Approach 3: Using normal UTC
#PYTHON**

from datetime import datetime, timezone

utc_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

utc_time_str = utc_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z+00:00")

utc_time_format = datetime.strptime(utc_time_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z+00:00")

expiration_time = int(utc_time_format.timestamp()) + 20

url_temp = f"https://example.com?expiration_time={expiration_time}"

**Approach 4: Using UTC with timedelta
#PYTHON**

from datetime import datetime, timezone,timedelta

utc_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

expire_time_modify =  utc_time  + timedelta(seconds=20)

expiration_time = int(utc_time_format.timestamp())

Comment: With all of your approaches one could easily edit the expiration date in the link.